# Memory Map of Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-address, base-address

If I had an array of size 10 with a base address of say `0x5600bc`. What would be the memory location of each element of the array and of the `ptr`?

Ex: What is `Arr[0]` address, would it be `0x5600bc`? & would that make `Arr[1]` be `0x5600c0`?

Comment: We need to know what the type of the array is, and what size that type is on your machine.

Comment: You can check this by any IDE like Visual Studio and Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

Given

```
typename foo[10] = { 0 };
```

Then `foo[0]` will be at some address, `(uintptr_t)&foo[0]`.

`foo[1]` is at `(uintptr_t)&foo[0] + sizeof typename`, and `foo[n]` is at `(uintptr_t)&foo[0] + n * sizeof typename`.

Like this (assuming a 4 byte type here)

```
0x00000000 arr[0] <- arr is a pointer to this location
0x00000004 arr[1]
0x00000008 arr[2]
...
```

If you have an array of 32-bit integers, that's 4 bytes each, and the array starts at `0x5600bc` then yes, `arr[1]` will be at `0x5600c0`.

You can print the addresses of each element in your array like so:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  #define ARR_SIZE 10
  int arr[ARR_SIZE] = {0};

  for (size_t n = 0; n < ARR_SIZE; ++n) {
    printf("arr[%zu] = %p\n", n, (void*)&arr[n]);
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: By `foo[0] + sizeof typename`, you mean `(uintptr_t)&foo[0] + sizeof typename`

Answer (score 2):

The location of `Arr[n]` will be `0x5600bc + n*sizeof(Arr[0])`. So if the size of the array elements is `4`, `Arr[1]` will indeed be at `0x5600c0`.

Answer (score 0):

Array name (identifier) is actually a pointer to its first element, so the answer to `Arr[0]` is `0x5600bc`. Depending on the `type` of the array and more specifically its `element size` (in bytes) will determine the increment of the address of each next element.

In general, [Indirect addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode) mode is used, where you have: 
`base address + offset`, where `base = array name`, `offset = (element size)*(index of element)`

Great explanations for [arrays](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) and [pointer and arrays](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/9/).

Graphical representation:
 [image]